# Concurrency handling php

Tags: concurrency, payment-gateway

I am having a site in this site user doing transaction.
When user doing a successful transaction come back to my site.
I am just check server server communication at the same time user have been refresh multiple time and users get money multiple times.

is there are Concurrency management in PHP.

Or any solution

Answer (score 0):

What payment solution are you using that this is happening with? In any production-environment code dealing with payments you do not want the code that updates your information to come from a user redirect from that website. You want to use an IPN system, and unique keys for each transaction to ensure that all data is valid and only submitted once. If you are not using an outside payment processor, then you will want to assign a unique key for each transaction that happens, and check that against your database to ensure the data is added/modified only once per transaction. I hope this makes sense.